# is that possible to get user name of a ppp connection after connected

Tags: linux, vpn, ppp

I have a PPTP server, and i want do something special (add an route) when some user connected,  and this should not affect other users.

I used to write scripts in /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/** ,but i cant find a way to identify whom the connection belongs to.

Does it ever possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using /var/log/wtmp and specifically the 'last' command to determine which user owns a particular connection. Something like this will give you a list of users who are still connected and their associated interface:

```
last | grep "ppp.*still logged in"
```

Hope it helps!